# How to create a new dataframe/CSV file from reading contents of files from various folders in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, directory

I have multiple folders which contains CSV files with values. I need to create a new dataframe/CSV file where contents of each column from each file and each folder is placed in this new dataframe

Folder-1

A1.CSV

```
       A       B      C       D
       aa      bb     cc      dd
```

Folder-2

B1.CSV

```
        E      F       G       H
        ee     ff      gg      hh
```

Folder-3

C1.CSV

```
         I      J       K       L
         ii     jj      kk      ll
```

D1.CSV

```
          M       N       O       P
          mm      nn      oo      pp
```

New-Dataframe should be

```
           A       B        C       D     E     F      H      I   O     P
           aa      bb       cc      dd    ee    ff     hh     ii  oo    pp
```

Comment: Could you please include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do assuming that the python script is at the root of subfolders:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Initiate result DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop over csv files in sub folders
for csv_file in glob.glob("*/*.csv"):
    
    # Concat each new DataFrame with the result
    result = pd.concat([result, pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',')], axis=1)
    
print(result)
```

pay attetntion to the csv separator.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for could be done with `pd.concat()`.

You'll have to iterate through each file in each folder, load the individual csv file as a new DataFrame, and then concatenate it to the rest of the dataframes along axis 1 (columns).

Assuming that your working directory is where all folders such as 'Folder-1', 'Folder-2', etc. are stored, and that no other folders/files are in that directory, you could use this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# First creating your 'complete DataFrame' as an empty DataFrame.
complete_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterating through folders and files to find each csv:
for folder_name in os.listdir():
    for csv_file in os.listdir(folder_name):
        # Loading the individual csv as a pandas DataFrame
        csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"{folder_name}/{csv_file}")

        # If complete_df is empty, overwrite it with the first csv df.
        if len(complete_df) == 0:
            complete_df = csv_df
        # Otherwise, add the new csv df to the current complete df.
        else:
            complete_df = pd.concat([complete_df, csv_df], axis=1)
```

The code also assumes that the only files in each folder are csv files.

For what it's worth, if your final DataFrame is literally going to be only one
row and many columns, I suggest transposing it such that it is instead multiple rows and only a single column -- it is much more efficient to store csv files in this format.

Note:
I have inserted the use of f-strings in the code above; these will only work if your Python version is 3.6+. If not, you should be able to replace this section with the .format() method, or using string addition.

Comment: Thanks, i'm getting error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File .azurefunctions/Folder-1 does not exist: '.azurefunctions/Folder-1

Comment: Its at line 11,  csv_df = pd.read_csv(f"{folder_name}/{csv_file}")

Comment: This is because your working directory does not appear to be the directory where the folders are contained. The code is reading `folder_name` as `.azurefunctions` and the `csv_file` as `Folder-1`. 
It seems to me that all your target folders are inside the `.azurefunctions` directory. Either change your working directory to be inside here, or add `.azurefunctions` to both `os.listdir()` calls, and the `read_csv` call.

Comment: I changed my working directory, still facing error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'folder_name'

Comment: Sorry you had trouble getting it to work. I can see that blondelg's solution helped, so I'll consider this solved.

Comment: Yes thank you for the help, I would try to implement both the solution